# Shapes in legend do not correspond to graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have two timeseries of data that I want represented by its individual datapoints with different shapes. The correct shape is displayed in the graph (circle and square), although the legend displays the same shape for both lines (and a step-wise line that does not need to indicated by points). How can I have a circle and a square in the legend for the glucose and CDW respectively and no shape for the substrate.

[image]

I've tried different options with scale_shape_manual, but none seemed to work.

```
data = read.table("Aps_F12_data_samples_raw.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM")

df = data[,c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10)]
names(df) = c("time", "glucose", "substrate_use", "alkyl", "bola", "oleyl", "cdw", "substrate")
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = time)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = cdw, colour = "CDW", shape="CDW"), size=2) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = glucose, colour = "glucose", shape="glucose"), size=2) + 
  geom_line(data=df[!is.na(df$cdw),], aes(y = cdw, colour = "CDW"), size=1) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = glucose, colour = "glucose"), size=1) + 
  geom_step(aes(y = substrate, colour = "substrate"), size=1, linetype="dashed") + 
  theme_classic() + ylab("Concentration (g/l)") +  
  xlab("Time (h)") + 
  scale_colour_manual(name="Time (h)", values = c("CDW" = "grey", "glucose"= "#fb6a4a", "substrate"= "black")) + 
  scale_shape_manual(name="Time (h)", values = c("CDW"=16, "glucose"=15)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0, 25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150), labels=c("0", "25", "50", "75", "100", "125", "150")) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.title=element_blank())

p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=time)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = alkyl, colour = "alkyl SS"), size=1) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = oleyl, colour = "bola SS"), size=1) + 
  theme_classic() + 
  xlab("Time (h)") + 
  ylab("Concentration (g/l)") + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("#addd8e", "#f7fcb9")) + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.title=element_blank())

grid.arrange(p1,p2)
```

```
time glucose substrate_use alkyl bola oleyl cdw substrate
0.00000 163 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  0
6.00000 165 NA  NA  NA  NA  1.0 0
24.16667    144 1.1559633   NA  NA  NA  13.2    0
31.16667    134 1.2317881   NA  NA  NA  14.4    0
49.86667    115 1.1398176   NA  NA  NA  18.6    0
77.21667    96  0.9688743   NA  NA  NA  17.4    0
94.28333    83  0.9288276   NA  NA  NA  18.4    0
103.35000   77  0.9039548   NA  NA  NA  18.4    0
103.75000   128 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  50
118.43333   122 0.4086266   NA  NA  NA  17.0    50
128.18333   119 0.3076923   NA  NA  NA  17.6    50
142.38333   111 0.5633803   NA  NA  NA  17.8    50
151.13333   107 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  50
166.25000   100 NA  NA  NA  NA  18.6    50
175.13333   95  NA  NA  NA  NA  18.8    50
190.03333   89  NA  NA  NA  NA  19.4    50
```

Comment: Map the same values to `shape` as to `color` and then use `scale_shape_manual`.

Comment: I am now getting two legends: one with color and one with the shape.  I've adjusted the code in my question.

Comment: If possible please include a subset of your data that we can work with. In order to get what you want you would likely have to change your data to long format, and then split the samples by aesthetic instead of using individual geom_* calls.

Comment: There is no entry for substrate in your shape scale.

Comment: I don't want a shape for the substrate, just a step-wise line graph. @rpolicastro I first tried with my data in long format, but found it more difficult to represent part of it as geom_line, part as geom_step.

Comment: You can add the substrate separately if you put it in its own data frame, and put that data frame as the first argument to geom_step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This combines the legends:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = time)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = cdw, colour = "CDW", shape="CDW"), size=2) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = glucose, colour = "glucose", shape="glucose"), size=2) + 
  #you need a mapping in geom_point for substrate:
  geom_point(aes(y = substrate, colour = "substrate", shape="substrate")) + 
  geom_line(data=df[!is.na(df$cdw),], aes(y = cdw, colour = "CDW"), size=1) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = glucose, colour = "glucose"), size=1) + 
  geom_step(aes(y = substrate, colour = "substrate"), size=1, linetype="dashed") + 
  theme_classic() + ylab("Concentration (g/l)") +  
  xlab("Time (h)") + 
  scale_colour_manual(name="Time (h)", values = c("CDW" = "grey", "glucose"= "#fb6a4a", "substrate"= "black")) + 
  #you can remove the points for substrate in the scale:
  scale_shape_manual(name="Time (h)", values = c("CDW"=16, "glucose"=15, substrate = NA)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0, 25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150), labels=c("0", "25", "50", "75", "100", "125", "150")) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.title=element_blank())
```